# :app:compileDebugJava Failed at Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, ide, android-studio, xdebug

I have checkout my project branch from SVN at Android Studio with slicSVN workspace.

but when I'm making rebuild whole project but

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   invalid source release: 1.7"

Why this issue had been arise ? [image]

Comment: Please attach your build files to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this issue, I'm using JDK6, but project built at JDK7, so I installed JDK7 and set path and java_home and run again, It's working fine....