# gradle build is successful but ":app:compileDebugJava FAILED" while running

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am trying to debug my app. 
when i click "sync project with gradle files", build is successful but when i try to run gradle console shows ":app:compileDebugJava FAILED" occurs.

this is my success build from gradle console.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.204 secs
```

and gradle console with error is as:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --    debug     option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.161 secs
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.+'
compile 'com.andrewreitz:shillelagh:0.5.0'
   provided 'com.andrewreitz:shillelagh-processor:0.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.+'
compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@jar'
   }
```

Comment: Post your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this issue, I'm using JDK6, but project built at JDK7, so I installed JDK7 and set path and java_home and run again, It's working fine....

[View this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805025/appcompiledebugjava-failed-at-android-studio-ide)

Comment: your error was "invalid source release: 1.7" i guess this is far different condition